# Apply Arrayformula to formula that shows the last cell of a row (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I go to the community to find out if there is a solution to my problem which I detail below, I have a data matrix which grows from cell to cell along rows, there are rows that have more data than others and through the formula that I will leave at the end I can obtain the last 3 values of each row up to that point the formulas fulfill their function but when I try to add the Arrayformula I cannot make the formulas work so that they are completed automatically, I would appreciate if you could help me with this problem.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1roYF0U5H-xsBOd6vsw95riaoKEjnptZs9yAeYoCceVQ/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, assuming there are no blank cells between the non-blank cells:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(
row(C2:C11),
{row(C2:C11),C2:I11},
mod(sequence(rows(C2:C11),3,0),3)+mmult(if(C2:I11<>"",1,0),sequence(COLUMNS(C2:I11),1,1,0))-1,
0))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the link to your document please?

Comment: Apologies, will be able to do it in a couple of hours

Comment: Could you try tis link plz? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wgVKKe25z9WwAafr2_on6PpuTVNsEx66C-BuVLgz0EM/edit#gid=0